# Manage dependencies of git submodules with poetry

Tags: python, dependencies, git-submodules, python-poetry

We have a repository *app-lib* that is used as sub-module in 4 other repos and in each I have to add all dependencies for the sub-module.
So if I add/remove a dependency in *app-lib* I have to adjust all other repositories. 
I there a way to tell Poetry to install the root repo dependencies and the ones in the sub-module?

The `my-package = { path = "../my-package/dist/my-package-0.1.0.tar.gz" }` parameter seems only to work for files. And I don't know if it's good design to store all wheels in *app-lib*.

I kind of want to merge the root toml file dependencies and the sub-module toml file dependencies and then install them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end if that helps someone I just build the submodule and store it in a private repo like Gitlab Packages or Nexus, loading it with poetry with the `peotry install`.

See https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/