# How to install the dependencies of the submodule using poetry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I have a project `my-project` that uses a submodule `my-submodule`. The submodule has dependencies different from `my-project` in `poetry.lock` & `pyproject.toml` files.

I have installed the dependencies required for `my-project` using `poetry add`. These deps are installed and `poetry.lock` & `pyproject.toml` files are created in the root folder of `my-project`.

Now, I would also like to install the dependencies of the submodule. Assuming that the path of the submodule is `path/to/submodule/from/root`, how can I install the dependencies of the submodule and make those deps reflect in the `poetry.lock` & `pyproject.toml` files of the root?

A similar question has been asked here: [Manage dependencies of git submodules with poetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727951/manage-dependencies-of-git-submodules-with-poetry), but there isn't a solution provided there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare the submodule as a `path` dependency in the `pyproject.toml` of the parent project. It will then treat the submodule as a package and include it in dependency install/resolution. Be sure to also include the `develop` attribute when declaring the dependency, as follows:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
my-package = { path = "./path/to/submodule/from/root", develop = true }
```

Link to docs: https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies

Comment: The tooltip for the `develop` attribute says "Whether to install the dependency in development mode.". What does that exactly mean?

Comment: Installing in development mode means that changes made to the source code of the dependency will be reflected immediately when running the project that includes it. In other words, it's not necessary to rebuild and re-import the dependency for changes to be picked up in the parent project.